# how to give chance to all clients one by one to send a number and block a client to send number if its not his chance in socket programming in java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sockets, arraylist

**Multiple clients and one server for bingo game**

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {

    int[][] card = new int[5][5];
    int[][] bingo = new int[5][5];

    public int[][] bingoCard() {

        ArrayList<Integer> alreadyUsed = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean valid = false;
        int tmp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < card.length; row++) {
                while (!valid) {
                    tmp = (int) (Math.random() * 25) + 1;
                    if (!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)) {
                        valid = true;
                        alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                    }
                }
                card[row][i] = tmp;
                bingo[row][i] = tmp;
                valid = false;
            }
        }

        //create array to make title.  
        String title[] = {"B", "I", "N", "G", "O"};

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(title[i] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int row = 0; row < card.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < card[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(card[row][col] + "\t");

            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        return bingo;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {

            ServerSocket serversct = new ServerSocket(1000);
            int counter = 0;
            System.out.println("Server Started ....");
            while (counter <= 2) {
                counter++;
                Socket serverClient = serversct.accept();  //server accept the client connection request
                System.out.println(" >> " + "Client No:" + counter + " started!");
                DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(serverClient.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(serverClient.getOutputStream());
                //bingo=Server.bingoCard();
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(serverClient.getOutputStream());

                ServerClientThread sct = new ServerClientThread(serverClient, counter, inStream, outStream, os, new Server().bingoCard()); //send  the request to a separate thread

                ServerClientThread.sockets.add(sct);
                if (counter == 1) {
                    ServerClientThread.chance.add(1);
                } else {
                    ServerClientThread.chance.add(0);
                }

            }


            ServerClientThread.distribute();

            //ServerClientThread.sockets.get(1).start();
            ServerClientThread.transferring();

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class ServerClientThread extends Thread {

    Socket serverClient;
    int clientNo;
    DataInputStream inStream;
    DataOutputStream outStream;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    static ArrayList<ServerClientThread> sockets = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> chance = new ArrayList<>();

    static ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> oosal = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<DataInputStream> datainputal = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<DataOutputStream> dataoutputal = new ArrayList<>();
    static int received;
    int[][] card = new int[5][5];
    int[][] bingo = new int[5][5];

    ServerClientThread(Socket inSocket, int counter, DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos, ObjectOutputStream oos, int abc[][]) {//,int abc[][]) {
        this.serverClient = inSocket;
        this.clientNo = counter;

        this.oos = oos;
        oosal.add(oos);

        this.inStream = dis;
        this.outStream = dos;
        ServerClientThread.datainputal.add(dis);
        ServerClientThread.dataoutputal.add(dos);
        this.bingo = abc;
    }
//i will use this run method later for checking winner of bingo card
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {


            System.out.println("thread is running");


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Client :" + clientNo + " exit!! ");
        }
    }

    public static void distribute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("distributing");

        for (int i = 0; i <= ServerClientThread.sockets.size() - 1; i++) {
            oosal.get(i).writeObject(ServerClientThread.sockets.get(i).bingo);
            System.out.println("i is +" + i);
        }

    }

    public static synchronized void transferring() throws Exception {



        while (true) {
                int chance = 1;
            int received = 10000;
            for (int i = 0; i <= ServerClientThread.datainputal.size() - 1; i++) {
                
                ServerClientThread.dataoutputal.get(i).writeInt(chance);
                ServerClientThread.dataoutputal.get(i).flush();
                
                for (int l = 0; l <= ServerClientThread.chance.size() - 1; l++) {

                    
                    if (ServerClientThread.chance.get(l) == 1)
                {
                    received = ServerClientThread.datainputal.get(i).readInt();
                }
                    if (l == i + 1)
                    {
                        ServerClientThread.chance.set(l, 1);
                    } 
                    else if (i == ServerClientThread.chance.size() - 1) {
                        ServerClientThread.chance.set(l, 0);
                        ServerClientThread.chance.set(0, 1);
                    } else {
                        ServerClientThread.chance.set(l, 0);
                    }


                }

                
                for (int n = 0; n< ServerClientThread.datainputal.size(); n++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j< ServerClientThread.datainputal.size(); j++)
                if(ServerClientThread.chance.get(n)==1 && ServerClientThread.datainputal.get(j).available()>0)
                {
                        received=ServerClientThread.datainputal.get(j).read();
                }}
                
               System.out.println("this is received" + received);
                

                chance = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j <= ServerClientThread.dataoutputal.size() - 1; j++) {

                    ServerClientThread.dataoutputal.get(j).writeInt(chance);
                    
                    ServerClientThread.dataoutputal.get(j).writeInt(received);
                    
                }

                chance = 1;
                for (int k = 0; k <= ServerClientThread.chance.size() - 1; k++) {
                    System.out.println("here is given chance" + ServerClientThread.chance.get(k));
                }
            }

        }
    }



    }

}
```

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Client {

    static String completed[] = new String[5];

    static int tosend;
    static int received1;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        try {

            // Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            // getting localhost ip 
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            int flag = 1;
            // establish the connection with server port 9999 
            Socket s = new Socket(ip, 1000);
            DataInputStream discl = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream doscl = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            int[][] array = (int[][]) is.readObject();
        
            //create array to make title.  
            String title[] = {"B", "I", "N", "G", "O"};

            for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(title[i] + "\t");
            }

            System.out.println();

            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print(array[row][col] + "\t");

                }
                System.out.println();

            }
        
            while (true) {

                int i = discl.readInt();
                    
                if (i == 1 ) 
                {
                       
                    System.out.println("inside i==1");
                    System.out.println("in if condition 1");
                    System.out.println("opening  scanner");
                   
                    tosend = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                    
                    
                    doscl.writeInt(tosend);
 
                } else if (i == 0) {

                    //sendComplete();
                    System.out.println("closing scanner");

                    System.out.println("inside i==2");
                    //completed = Bingo;
                    System.out.println("in if condition 0");

                    received1 = discl.readInt();
                    System.out.println(received1);


                }

            }

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }

    }

}
```

Aactually i am developing Bingo card game, after distributing bingo card to each client, game begins and each client will play one by one and send a number to server and then server will send that number to all clients this is the repeatedly process,
as i said all client will send number one by one if client follow this flow then the execution of the program is as i want **i am stucked on a situation that is   if client enters two numbers at a time** **then after completing all other clients chance ,when chance comes to that particular client who entered two numbers will not get chance and the second number entered by this client will be considered as his played number. i want to stop listening from server side to accept numbers if a client enters more than one number at a time.